# Combine table in Loop in R

Tags: r

```
library(XML)
file <- read.csv("temp_read_by_r.csv", header=FALSE)
for (n in 1:5)
{
theurl <- as.character(file[n,1])
table <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
newdata <- do.call("rbind", table)
}
```

When I run the above code, the `newdata`gives the table available in 5th url, however I'm looking for a combined data from 1 to 5.

Any Help. (new to R)

Comment: You will need to give more information on what your tables look like and what you want as result. Are all tables structured the same? Do you want a data frame where each table is a row and each tables' contents are in the columns? Do you want a list of table? ...

Comment: Of course, you're overwriting `newtable` on each loop. Try the solution provided by @nongkrong, or append "append" `newtable` on each loop

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(file, function(x) readHTMLTable(x)))
```

This uses `lapply` to loop over you files, then call `rbind`  on the resulting list.  In your code, because you assign to `newdata` within your loop, that variable is overwritten on each iteration.

`file` and `table` are function names in R, so those names might be confusing.